# ThinkPad hard-drive motion detection support

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad

I am running `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` on a ThinkPad X220. Does Ubuntu support the hard-drive "motion detection" features that I have always found on ThinkPads, since I first got an X31 running Windows XP? (e.g. detect tilts, park hard-drive heads, show detailed status, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

HDAPS daemon for IBM/Lenovo ThinkPads and Apple iBooks/PowerBooks

This is a disk protection user-space daemon. It monitors the acceleration
values through the HDAPS or AMS interface and automatically initiates disk
head parking if a fall or sliding of the laptop is detected.

It is recommended that you use this daemon with the hdaps module provided
by tp-smapi rather the one in the kernel, as this will save you a bit
power and will work on a wider range of ThinkPads.

See synaptic or the software center to install.

REF:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_protect_the_harddisk_through_APS

hdapsd package: http://packages.debian.org/unstable/misc/hdapsd